# Why doesn't my code write to a text file?

Tags: java, file, text-files, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I want to know why my code doesn't write to a text file, JVM doesn't throw any exceptions...

```
public class AlterData {

    Data[] information; 
    File informationFile = new File("/Users/RamanSB/Documents/JavaFiles/Information.txt");
    FileWriter fw;

    public void populateData(){
        information = new Data[3];

        information[0] = new Data("Big Chuckzino", "Custom House", 18);
        information[1] = new Data("Rodger Penrose", "14 Winston Lane", 19);
        information[2] = new Data("Jermaine Cole", "32 Forest Hill Drive", 30);
    }

    public void writeToFile(Data[] rawData){
        try{    
        fw = new FileWriter(informationFile);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        for(Data people : rawData){ 
            bw.write(people.getName()+ ", ");
            bw.write(people.getAddress() + ", ");
            bw.write(people.getAge() +", |");
            }
        }catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
            AlterData a1 = new AlterData();
            a1.populateData();
            a1.writeToFile(a1.information); 
    }
}
```

Comment: where is `bw.close()`.

Comment: Also have a look at [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling `bw.flush()` after writing the data and then you have to close the stream with `bw.close()` after flushing.

When closing the `BufferedWriter` it would be best to put the `close` statement into a finally block to ensure that the stream is closed, no matter what.

You should also look into using a try with resource. This makes use of the `AutoCloseable` feature of `BufferedWriter` as follows:

```
try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("path/to/file")))) {
     // Do something with writer      
} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

That way java will make sure that the stream is closed for you when leaving the try body, no matter what happens.

Answer (score 2):

You should call `close` or `flush` for the `BufferedWriter` instance in order to flush the data into the file. Anyway, it's always important to close any resource you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that, we need flush() to push the changes to file,
**Also ensure that you are closing the File resources:**

```
public void writeToFile(Data[] rawData){
        BufferedWriter bw = null;
        try{    
        fw = new FileWriter(informationFile);
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        for(Data people : rawData){ 
            bw.write(people.getName()+ ", ");
            bw.write(people.getAddress() + ", ");
            bw.write(people.getAge() +", |");
            }
        }catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
               if(fw  != null) {
                     fw.close();
                     fw = null;
               }
               if(bw  != null) {
                     bw.close();
                     bw = null;
               }
        }
    }
```